# How do I override Activerecord gem with my own in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

We've found an error in the code for multi-schema databases in ActiveRecord (we're fairly positive it's an error, atleast ;).  So we've patched the file and submitted a pull request to rails core etc.

However, we would like to deploy our fix and not await the inclusion of our fix in a next release of rails. Our app is hosted on Heroku.

**Question:**
How do i specify in my Gemfile that it should pull the activerecord gem not from its default location but, for example, from my repository at Github ?

Thanks for your help and time,
Erwin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `:git` parameter with git path to your Gemfile:

```
gem "nokogiri", :git => "git://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri.git"
```

It is very well described at http://gembundler.com/

Comment: Yes, but activerecord is part of the rails dependencies. My gem file only specifies 'gem rails'. Can i add a second line to it to explicitly specify it should pull activerecord from somewhere else?

Comment: I think you can try with second line, but I'm not sure if it will work. Try it out.